# Eсли and бы - Can you tell me why these sentences are all different?

Tags: грамматика

First of all: can I use `Eсли` without `бы` or `бы` without `Eсли`?

As I see here, the first and the second start with `Eсли бы` but in the second part of the sentence just `бы` remains:

> Eсли бы я был богат, я бы не работал.
>
> Если бы я изучал медицину, я был бы врач.

So, the difference is:

- in the first sentence: бы я был
- and in the second one: я был бы

why there is another structure?

In the third I can not understand why there is a genitive or accusative case for "me" instead of `я`:

> Если меня здесь не было, я бы не хотел изучать русский язык.

Also in the first part there is no `бы`.

can you help me?

Comment: if you can read Russian, this article might be of interest to you: http://elementy.ru/lib/431049

Comment: "Если меня здесь не было, я бы не хотел изучать русский язык." - this is a wrong sentence, there should be бы here.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all: can I use Eсли without бы or бы without Eсли?

`бы` is a way to express [Subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) in Russian. Verb forms are translated into English with *would / could* when `бы` is used.

So to answer your question: yes, you can but that changes the meaning. Everything with `бы` is not real.

> why there is another structure?

This looks like a word order question. Why `если бы я был` and not `если я был бы`? First of all there are things you have to take for granted when learning a language.

But the explanation can be like this: the sooner you introduce `бы` the better because it changes everything: real to unreal.

Plus `бы` is so flexible that it can be practically anywhere in a sentence not to mention that it can be repeated many times in one sentence (in colloquial speech):

```
Я бы хотел бы ...
```

> Если меня здесь не было, я бы не хотел изучать русский язык.

This is not correct (grammatically and stylistically). To fix grammar:

```
Если бы меня здесь не было, я бы не хотел изучать русский язык.
```

Basically it means: If I were not here I wouldn't want to learn Russian. To fix both:

```
Если бы я сюда не приехал, я бы не стал изучать русский язык.
```

> why there is a genitive or accusative case for "me" instead of я

There is a difference between personal and [impersonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_verb) verbs. Compare:

`Я не здесь. Я не был здесь.` - personal

`Меня здесь нет. Меня здесь не было.` - impersonal

So `I` is not in *Nominative* (`я`) but in *Genitive* (`меня`) because `I` is not a *subject* but an *object* in these sentences.

Comment: 1. so, if I use just бы is not real, but if I add also Если would be real? And if I use just Если? when I can use just one or another, or when I should use both?
2. so you added бы but why меня and not Я? and it's a genitive or accusative case?
thanks

Comment: 1. Если станешь богат, то не надо будет работать. - If you get rich, you won't have to work. - Is it real or not real? If you got rich, you wouldn't have to work. - Is it more unreal than the previous example? Both are not real but the second case adds more doubt. 2. impersonal sentence. you can make it personal: Если бы я был не здесь, я бы не хотел изучать русский язык.

Answer (score 2):

"Бы" в современном языке считается частицей, но восходит она к аористу (форме прошедшего времени) глагола "быти", так что употреблять "бы" можно только с глаголом прошедшего времени (т.е. условное наклонение изначально было составным глагольным временем).

Таким образом условное наклонение с "бы" всегда относится к прошедшему времени и означает ситуацию, которая *не имела места быть в прошлом* по какой-либо причине. Следует также упомянуть, что кроме того существует несколько особых случаев употребления "бы", например, вежливое пожелание аналогично "would": "Не хотели бы Вы...?" - "Would you like...?"

Соответственно, конструкция только с "если" без "бы" означает действие или ситуацию, которые в принципе могли произойти в прошлом или могут произойти в настоящем или будущем.

Answer (score 0):

### How the particle <kbd>бы</kbd> logically works.

```
           they told about pure logical condition
           irrespective of the time
   ┌────────┴──────────┐
    Если бы я был богат, я бы не работал. 
    Если    я был богат, я бы не работал. 
   └────────┬──────────┘
          they told narrowed, about logical condition
          on scene in the past

               (1)                 (2)  
    ┌───────────┴────────────┐┌─────┴───────┐
    Если бы я изучал медицину, я был бы врач.
    supposed the (1), it hardly implies the (2), 
    irrespective of the time,
    and scenes (1),(2) may be different.


               (1)                 (2)  
    ┌───────────┴────────────┐┌─────┴───────┐    
    Если    я изучал медицину, я был бы врач.
    supposed the (1) on scene in the past, the (2) arises logically from the (1),  
    and the (2) is irrespective of the time,
    and scenes (1),(2) may be different.

               (1)                   (2)  
    ┌───────────┴────────────┐┌───────┴───────┐     
    Если    я изучал медицину, я был    врачом.
    supposed the (1) on scene in the past, 
    the fact is that the (2) is the fact 
    in the same scene.
```

---

The sentence given in the OP

```
Если меня здесь не было, я бы не хотел изучать русский язык.
```

is logically equivalent to

```
Если [object] здесь [verb], then ... .
```

Given that the sentence is, in particular, equivalent to

```
Если деревья свалило ветром, then ... .
```

we need only take a look at my [answer here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-vs-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/8837#8837), to illustrate a point.

Comment: thank you very much for your patience, it's almost clear, the use of Если and бы, the thing that I can not really understand It's the use of genitive Меня. If "I" person is not the subject and the object, who is the subject, then?
thank you all for your time and patience, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @mario , please see my update.