# Verb was with masculine noum

Tags: грамматика, падежи, склонение, род

Why in the following sentence we use
`было` instead of `был`, since we're talking about the husband? (Муж in this case).

*Жена́ не выходи́ла из свои́х ко́мнат, му́жа тре́тий день не бы́ло до́ма.*

English: *The wife did not leave her own room, the husband had not been at home for three days.*

I'm trying to follow an audiobook without worrying about grammar, but trying also to 'confirm' what i already know (or thought i knew lol).

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [“Деревья свалил ветер” vs “Деревья свалило ветром”](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/8829/2060)

Comment: Wrong stress: `не бы́ло до́ма` should be `не́ было до́ма`. Although "не" is written separately, yet it must be pronounced as one word: "нЕбыло".

Comment: Thanks, i've copy-pasted from a site. Do you have some reference for this particular topic? I find very hard to read while listening.

Comment: @Fernando ["не дАл" или "нЕ дал?"](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is so called **impersonal sentence** (*безличное предложение*). In your case the main member of the sentence is expressed with a negative form of the predicate (*не было*) in combination with a noun in the genitive (*мужа*). Here the emphasis is on the **absence** of the husband (*There was no husband at home*), while "муж не был дома" tells us about **non-attendance** of the husband (*The husband was not at home*). Verbs in impersonal sentences come in the form of neuter gender, singular.

Examples,
Personal affirmative sentences, nominative case:

- *Я дома* - I am home
- *Я был дома* - I was home
- *Я буду дома* - I will be home

Impersonal negative sentences, genitive case:

- *Меня нет дома* - I am not home, there is not me in the house, the house is "empty"
- *Меня не было дома* - I was not home, there was not me...
- *Меня не будет дома* - I will not be home, there will not be me...

Personal negative sentences, nominative case:

- *Я не дома* - I am not home, I am in some other place
- *Я не был дома* - I was not home, I didn't visit it (as a fact of visiting)
- *Я не буду дома* - I will not be home, I will not visit it (as a fact of visiting)

Comment: Большой спасибо!