# What is the omitted neuter subject of the verb "оглушить/оглушило" here?

Tags: грамматика

> Эта каменная глыба свалилась с неба... меня наверно **оглушило** ударной волной.

- The "глыба" is a feminine noun...
- The feminine "волной" is in Instrumental, so it cannot be the subject...
- As far as I know, the verb "оглушить" does not take the impersonal subject...

Comment: Related: “Деревья свалил ветер” vs “Деревья свалило ветром” https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-vs-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: "меня [наверно] оглушило ..." - is a [Безличное предложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, you can imagine something like “нечто” as an implied subject: нечто оглушило меня.

This is a common way of expressing impersonal sentences: Урожай побило градом. Дом завалило снегом. Где шляпа? — Ветром унесло.

You could rephrase your sentence with an explicit subject: Ударная волна оглушила меня. See ["Деревья свалил ветер" vs "Деревья свалило ветром"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/8829/) for what semantic nuances this implies.